# Как правильно пишется: "был одним из восьмерых" или "был одним из восьми"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, числительные, собирательные-числительные

Как правильно пишется: *был одним из восьмерых* или *был одним из восьми*?

Answer (score 3):

В сочетании с о д у ш е в л е н н ы м и существительными собирательные числительные употребляются как в именительном, так и в косвенных падежах: трое детей, мать троих детей.

В сочетании с н е о д у ш е в л е н н ы м и существительными используется, как правило, только форма именительно-винительного падежа: двое саней, трое ножниц, четверо суток. В косвенных падежах используются формы соответствующих количественных числительных: к двум саням, с тремя ножницами, около четырёх суток.

[Употребление собирательных числительных](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/382/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

***В вашем случае можно выразиться двояко. Но лучше всё-таки ОДИН ИЗ ВОСЬМИ, так как только собирательные числительные ДВОЕ, ТРОЕ, ЧЕТВЕРО привычны и употребляются часто, остальные - очень редко.***

Answer (score 3):

"Из восьмерых" возможно только если среди этих людей есть мужчины. Тогда выбор зависит от контекста. Если нужен акцент на единстве восьми человек, то "из восьмерых", если на количестве людей, то "из восьми".

Задержанная банда состояла из восьми человек. Одним из (этих) восьмерых оказался известный контрабандист Карлос. И лишь одним из восьми наркоторговцев были даны признательные показания.

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от ситуации:

Он был одним из восьмерых детей в этой семье (собирательность обозначена).

Он был одним из восьми детей, получивших главные награды (указывается количество детей, получивших награды).

Answer (score 0):

> как правильно пишется: одним из восьмерых или одним из восьми?

ПРИМЕРЫ:

*Он был одним из восьмерых детей...*

*Он был одним из восьми детей...*

По-моему, никакой разницы. *Что в лоб, что по лбу.*